# How can I compare two blobs in c# in a way so I can patch it later

Tags: c#, data-analysis

I would like to write a program which compares two byte[] blob and returns the difference and a parch object so i can apply the patch on the original blob and get the other.

Is there any library out there which supports this?

I want to do the following:

```
public void myFunc(byte[] b1, byte[] b2)
{
    Patch myPatch = diff(b1,b2);
    byte[] b3 = myPatch.run(b1);
    b3==b2;  //should be true
}
```

I have been looking for a simple solution with no luck. can anybody help me?

Comment: deleted my comment as I was mislead. Re-read the meta of this website and this does indeed fall inside the website content guidelines